# how do we perform validation on a apex:inputfield in a apex:repeat tag in VF page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a Vf page which shows a list in a apex:repeat tag. All the fields displayed are apex:inputfield. There are 2 fields

1. quantity__c
2. Change__c

I want to validate, if the quantity has changed then i want the change field should 
be filled/mandatory. Can i do this validation at VF level?

Any other way of accomplishing this?

Thanks

Update: Here is code i am using as suggested by LaceySnr. I can see the apex message is thrown in the debug log but its not visible in Vfpage

```
     for (integer i=0;i<List_FinalStdItems.size();i++)
    {
        system.debug('inside loop to check quantity is changed');
        ItemSet.add(List_FinalStdItems[i].id);
        system.debug('New quantity'+List_FinalStdItems[i].quantity__c +'  old quantity'+MapStdItemsOldMap.get(List_FinalStdItems[i].id).quantity__c);
     //   system.debug('old quantity'+MapStdItemsOldMap.get(List_FinalStdItems[i].id).quantity__c);
        if (MapStdItemsOldMap.get(List_FinalStdItems[i].id).quantity__c!=List_FinalStdItems[i].quantity__c)
        {
            system.debug('This quantity for item '+List_FinalStdItems[i].Name+ ' has changed');
            if(List_FinalStdItems[i].Inventory_Change_Reason__c==null || List_FinalStdItems[i].Inventory_Change_Reason__c=='')
            {
                system.debug('This quantity for item '+List_FinalStdItems[i].Name+ ' has changed and Reason for change is empty');
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Reason for change not entered for changed Quantity'));
                error=true;
            }
        }
    }


01:04:55.541 (541902000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[151]|ApexPages.addMessage(ApexPages.Message)
01:04:55.541 (541985000)|VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|Reason for change not entered for changed Quantity
01:04:55.542 (542008000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[151]|ApexPages.addMessage(ApexPages.Message)
```

**Edit**

```
 <apex:outputpanel id="mess">
<apex:pageMessages />
</apex:outputpanel>
.
.
.
 <apex:actionFunction name="save" action="{!Save}" rerender="mess"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this through javascript directly, or you could use `<apex:actionSupport>` with the `onChange` event to refresh the second field, but to be honest I think the simplest and most robust way would be to just do the validation in the controller before saving a record.

**Edit**

I assume you have an `<apex:pageMessages/>` tag in the page, make sure you're rerendering it — i.e. if you're not doing a whole page refresh, put the messages tag in an output panel and specify that `<apex:outputPanel>` in the `rerender` attribute for your action.

**Edit II**

Is your action definitely returning a `null` `Pagereference`? Otherwise what you have looks correct. Are there any page blocks etc. between your action function and the output panel? If so you  may need to drill down through an id hierarchy.

Comment: my main concern is how do i verify if the field has changed, Do you suggest i loop through the list and check with the list which hold previous values ?

Comment: That's how I would do it, just keep a map of record id -> old value and then check against that.

Comment: i am able get the apex:messages in debug log but not shown in VF page. Any idea what could be the reason

Comment: updated the question.. still cant get the message to display. the whole page seems to get refreshed

Comment: i identified the problem with the way i was calling the javascript function. I had to give a return false. This was causing the page to refresh